What does "the other way" mean?
In Killers Of The Flower Moon (2023), right after Ernest asked Tom White to convey a message to Mollie,
who is sick, that Ernest wants to send her a letter, Agent Tom White
apprehended Ernest Burkhart for the Osage murders:

Journalist: Where they taking you, Mr. Burkhart?
Burkhart: I'm, uh--I'm going the other way for a while now.

What does "the other way" mean?

Sounds like argot for the penitentiary, time in prison.  Probably better asked on english.stackexchange.com

Do you know its literal meaning? It literally means in a different direction from other people. What that means in context is for the film critics to work out.
